# Is it possible to use a static private method of a class as callback?

Tags: php, callback, private-methods

I saw code that contained the following line:

```
preg_replace_callback($regex, 'TextileParser::replaceAnchor', $text);
```

where `TextileParser::replaceAnchor()` is a private static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Just test it yourself:
`<?php`

class TestCallBack {
    private static function found_number($num) {
        return "-".$num[0]."-";
    }
    public function find($Str) {
        return preg_replace_callback('/[0-9]/', 'TestCallBack::found_number', $Str);
    }
}
// Exemple
$Tester = new TestCallBack;
$Result = $Tester->find("54321");
var_dump($Result);

Comment: I reinstalled the OS on my computer, and I still have to enable PHP on it. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

on php's website, there's this example:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php#96899

I'd assume if it's on php.net, then it's good to go.

Comment: Comments written on php.net are not verified; the fact somebody reported that code doesn't mean PHP allows to use a private static method as callback. I noted the code reported in that comment, but I have not noticed anything in the documentation that reports it's possible.